# Decrypt SNMPv3 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming, snmp, pysnmp

I have the raw packet capture of an SNMPv3 snmpwalk

```
###[ Raw ]### 
  load      = '0>\x02\x01\x030\x11\x02\x04,\xa6\xceD\x02\x03\x00\xff\xe3\x04\x01\x04\x02\x01\x03\x04\x100\x0e\x04\x00\x02\x01\x00\x02\x01\x00\x04\x00\x04\x00\x04\x000\x14\x04\x00\x04\x00\xa0\x0e\x02\x04}q\x1d6\x02\x01\x00\x02\x01\x000\x00'
```

I know the Engine ID, the username, the password, the auth protocol, and the privacy protocol. How do I decrypt this raw payload into human-readable format?

What I've tried so far:

Using binascii I managed to get the hex string of the bytearray:

303e02010330110204589b95da020300ffe30401040201030410300e0400020100020100040004000400301404000400a00e02040b5d6c830201000201003000

However, I'm not sure in which order do I need to unhash it or decrypt it ?

Comment: You should use a library like `pysnmp` to perform the entire SNMP operations, if your goal is to talk to an SNMP device and grab the data. However, if your goal is to analyze SNMP conversation and troubleshoot, then the answer below shows you the right tool to use.

Comment: @LexLi - Unfortunately I neither need to issue a SNMP request nor use a third-party tool. My usecase is responding to an SNMP request to mimic a real device for use in testing hence why I cannot use Wireshark. I can provide more info if required but all I need to know is if I have all elements, where do I start, do I just decrypt using AES with the password or does the Engine ID factor into it somehow as like a salt?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the Authentication and Privacy keys, then you input them
into Wireshark SNMP Protocol Preferences and it will decrypt and
decode for you. We do it all the time.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I need to do it manually as I'm programmatically responding to SNMP requests using Scapy to mimic a real device during test.

Comment: You are re-inventing the wheel and implementing a SNMP simulator? Google it and there are more than 10, free and commercial, including ours. You get what you pay for.

Comment: And these SNMP simulators can respond to SNMP requests with whatever data I desire? For example, an SNMP get on the uptime I may want to return something like 5 or 50000 ?

Comment: I cannot tell you about others, but that is the most basic functionality of ours, to pause time at whatever time you want, whether 5 Timeticks, or 5 years. Been there for 20 years.

Comment: OK, this is integrated in Python too?

Comment: Also you say 'pause time' - I'm not wanting to pause time, I'm wanting to respond to SNMPv3 requests with custom defined data